# Are diazo theme files stored on the filesystem?

Tags: plone

Are diazo theme files stored on the filesystem?
If so where?
Is it possible to make changes to a theme file using an editing program (not the mapper screen)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the theme editor in Plone 4.3, right? Some themes are stored on the filesystem, some are stored in the ZODB.

For example, when you activate Diazo editing on a fresh Plone 4.3 instance you get a 'Twitter Bootstrap Example' theme under the Theming control panel. That theme is stored on the filesystem as part of the [plone.app.theming](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming) package. You can inspect the theme through the UI but you can't edit it - Plone isn't about to overwrite files in one of its own packages.

If you press the 'Copy' button you get a copy of that theme, stored in the ZODB. This one is editable, but only through the theme editor mechanisms*. Those mechanisms are pretty good though - you have the ACE editor (through [plone.resourceeditor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.resourceeditor)) at your disposal.

(*[if you're brave you could try editing a ZODB-stored theme via webdav](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12303))

If you press the 'Download' button you get a zip file that you can extract and edit using traditional text editing tools. You'll need to re-zip and upload to test your changes though.

My preferred way to setup a Diazo theme is on the filesystem as part of a Python package (again, see [plone.app.theming](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming#deploying-and-testing-themes)). I can use the rules inspector to figure out rules, but all the editing happens on the filesystem, in my favourite text editor. Once the site is in production, the theme editor gives me the power to quickly copy the Diazo theme and tweak it in-place without touching the filesystem. Later I can download the zip and use it to update my canonical filesystem version.

Details of the options and how the mechanisms work is well covered by the [plone.app.theming](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming) and [plone.resource](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.resource) documentation.

Comment: the editor is having issues... the file tree lists the files on one row horizontally, and some files never load into the editor. Which project own's these bugs?

Comment: These packages are part of Plone core, so [follow the standard Plone bug report procedure](http://plone.org/documentation/faq/i-think-ive-found-a-bug-in-plone.-where-should-i-report-it).